# Search mechanism on symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, search

I am writing a diploma in symfony 5 and studying symfony in parallel. I reached the implementation of the search in the table. I have a search field

```
<div class="search__container">
    <div class="search__block">
        <img class="search__glass" src="{{ asset('images/search-glass.svg')}}">
        <input class="search__field" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

and the actual table itself, which is output as follows

```
<div class="table__body">
    {% block table_items %}
        {% for item in items %}
            <div class="body__item">
                <a class="item__detail" href="item.html"></a>
                <img class="item__icon" src="images/icons/{{ item.extension }}.svg">
                <div class="item__title">{{ item.fileName }}</div>
                <div class="item__extension">{{ item.extension }}</div>
                <div class="item__updated">{{ item.uploaded }}</div>
                <div class="item__size">{{ item.size }}b</div>
                <div class="item__act">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <div class="action__popap">
                        <ul class="actions__list">
                            <li class="act__item detail">
                                <a href="detail/{{ item.id }}">Detail</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="act__item delete">
                                <a href="delete/{{ item.id }}">Delete</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="act__item download">
                                <a href="download/{{ item.id }}">Download</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

I want to do a search by "item.fileName" without reloading the page. And when I started doing it, I was at a dead end, not knowing what to do. I can do this with a page reload, but as for me it is not very convenient.

So, how can i do this?

I hope you can help me or point me to the correct vector.

Comment: You need to use javascript and replace the content of your table with the results.